# How can I remove deprecated messages from error reporting in php?

Tags: php, error-handling, deprecated

This is my php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

here my .htaccess:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
```

Still I see the deprecated messages on my page. How can I remove them?

Comment: I would rather suggest you to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given code removes only deprecated messages wich are emitted at run-time.

However, many deprecated messages are emitted at compile-time. These messages can only be hidden by updating the error_reporting value in your php.ini file.

With the following php.ini setting, you can hide deprecated messages by default:

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`